# postgres - operator does not exist: double precision ~~ unknown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

> ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator
>   does not exist: double precision ~~ unknown
>   2016-04-10T23:45:59.506005+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: ... =
>   "trackers"."category_id" WHERE (categories.tag LIKE '1.%'...

this is the error i get when i try to run this line of code here

```
Tracker.group(:category_id).joins(:category).where('categories.tag LIKE ? AND user_id = ?', "#{tag.to_i}.%", current_user.id)
```

tag is of type **float**, and i typecast it to an **integer** in order to check for tags 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 etc

so in the example above I type cast tag with value 1.0 to be 1, so i can search for tags that are like 1.1, 1.2 etc

I am using postgres on heroku that gives this error. locally i use sqlite3 and it works just fine.

how can i overcome this?

Comment: You're using a string function (LIKE) on a numeric type (float), postgres being a grown up DB (compared to SQLL) will negate such searches.  If you're searching for all 1.0 to 1.9 why don't you execute where tag >= 1.0 and tag <= 1.9

Comment: yeah i now get that, but i need it to work for many values not only between 1.0, 1.9. it could be between 2.0 and 2.9 or whatever, thats why i need it to be dynamic. is there a way to do it or?

Comment: Since you're in rails, why don't you sort out the dynamic-ness in rails first then send that to the ORM. 

The syntax you provided already accepts any parameters (eg: WHERE tag between ? and ?), so before you request the data from the ORM, sort out in rails the high and lows. The query is already setup for something to be dynamic.

Comment: @EdBaker thank you this helped me fix the problem. if you want to make an answer out of it, please do, that way i will help you too. cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're in rails, sort out the dynamic-ness in rails first then send that to the ORM. The syntax you provided already accepts any parameters (eg: WHERE tag between ? and ?), so before you request the data from the ORM, sort out in rails the high and lows. The query is already setup for something to be dynamic.